# How to interact with FIDO authenticaor (*user presence check*) from Windows Service?

Tags: cygwin, openssh, windows-services, fido2

I have a setup with several on-demand SSH tunnels that I like to manage via Windows Services. I normally use Cygwin with its own OpenSSH (OpenSSH_9.5p1, OpenSSL 3.0.12 24 Oct 2023), but have also tried Microsoft's OpenSSH port (OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.4p1, LibreSSL 3.7.3). I use Cygwin's `cygrunsrv` to manage these SSH tunnels as Windows Services, throwing in `autossh` into the mix. I've been using this setup for about 10 years now, and it worked **amazingly** well. Now I'm trying to get everything to work with a FIDO authenticator, and there's trouble.

With both abovementioned SSH implementations, I can successfully connect to a server with an ed25519_sk private key, touching my FIDO authenticator when asked.

However, I've been unsuccessful trying to get the user presence prompt when the connection is made via a Windows Service. The problem seems to be, that Windows Services are detached from the user's desktop session and cannot easily interact with the user. Indeed, [Microsoft recommends having a desktop application running which handles user interactions when needed by your service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/larryosterman/interacting-with-services) (at least as one of the solutions).

**The question: Is there a way to interact with the user and allow the presence to be proven, when either port of SSH is running as a Windows Service?**

---

## What have I tried?

### "Normal" connection attempts

#### Windows ssh interactively

```
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
Confirm user presence for key ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug1: find_helper: using "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\ssh-sk-helper.exe" as helper
User presence confirmed
Authenticated to ...
```

#### Windows ssh as a windows-service:

```
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com SHA256:...
debug3: notify_start: cannot notify: no display
debug1: find_helper: using "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\ssh-sk-helper.exe" as helper
debug3: Creating process with CREATE_NO_WINDOW
debug3: spawning "C:\\Program Files\\OpenSSH\\ssh-sk-helper.exe" as subprocess
debug3: start_helper: started pid=18372
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: process_sign: ready to sign with key ED25519-SK, provider internal: msg len 186, compat 0x4000000
debug1: sshsk_sign: provider "internal", key ED25519-SK, flags 0x01
debug1: ssh_sk_sign: fido_dev_get_assert: FIDO_ERR_INTERNAL
debug1: sshsk_sign: sk_sign failed with code -1
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Signing failed: invalid format
debug1: main: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -4
debug3: reap_helper: pid=18372
debug1: identity_sign: sshkey_sign: invalid format
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk": invalid format
```

Interactive works, as a windows service it doesn't.

#### Cygwin ssh interactively

The success case with Cygwin OpenSSH is very similar to the Windows one (not reproduced here for brevity).

#### Cygwin ssh as a windows service

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com SHA256:...
debug3: no authentication agent, not adding key
debug3: notify_start: cannot notify: no display
debug3: start_helper: started pid=62202
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: start_helper: starting /usr/sbin/ssh-sk-helper
debug1: process_sign: ready to sign with key ED25519-SK, provider internal: msg len 186, compat 0x4000000
debug1: sshsk_sign: provider "internal", key ED25519-SK, flags 0x01
debug1: ssh_sk_sign: fido_dev_get_assert: FIDO_ERR_INTERNAL
debug1: sshsk_sign: sk_sign failed with code -1
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Signing failed: invalid format
debug1: main: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -4
debug3: reap_helper: pid=62202
debug1: identity_sign: sshkey_sign: invalid format
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "/home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk": invalid format
```

In both failing cases, the problem seems to be that no window can be created, i.e. direct interaction with the user is impossible as a Windows Service. This is in-line with the changes since Windows Vista and the recommendation by Microsoft resources.

### SSH agent-mediated connection attempts

Now I thought that SSH agent would help. Both Windows and Cygwin SSH work with their own respective ssh-agents successfully (output skipped, nothing interesting). However, when running as a windows service:

#### Windows ssh + ssh-agent:

```
debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com SHA256:...
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "C:\\Users\\.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk" from agent: agent refused operation
```

#### Cygwin ssh + ssh-agent:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com SHA256:...
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '~/.ssh-agent'
debug3: no authentication agent, not adding key
debug3: notify_start: cannot notify: no display
debug3: start_helper: started pid=62407
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
debug1: start_helper: starting /usr/sbin/ssh-sk-helper
debug1: process_sign: ready to sign with key ED25519-SK, provider internal: msg len 186, compat 0x4000000
debug1: sshsk_sign: provider "internal", key ED25519-SK, flags 0x01
debug1: ssh_sk_sign: fido_dev_get_assert: FIDO_ERR_INTERNAL
debug1: sshsk_sign: sk_sign failed with code -1
debug1: ssh-sk-helper: Signing failed: invalid format
debug1: main: reply len 8
debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 5
debug1: client_converse: helper returned error -4
debug3: reap_helper: pid=62407
debug1: identity_sign: sshkey_sign: invalid format
sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for ED25519-SK "/home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk": invalid format
```

I thought that the ssh-agent would solve the problem, but for some reason it didn't work.

### Similar questions

[Why does ssh-agent with sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com key produces agent refused operation](https://superuser.com/questions/1792060/why-does-ssh-agent-with-sk-ssh-ed25519openssh-com-key-produces-agent-refused-op) This one seems fundamentally similar, albeit purely linux-based.

Answer (score 2):

The more I thought about the problem, the less it made sense that it didn't work with SSH agent. The SSH agent *should* take over the responsibility of handling FIDO authentication. And since it *can* interact with the user's desktop session, there should be no issue when a windows service asks it for authentication help.

Regarding Cygwin SSH agent not working, I eventually became suspicious about the line:

```
debug3: ssh_get_authentication_socket_path: path '~/.ssh-agent'
debug3: no authentication agent, not adding key
```

I had been starting my agent with `ssh-agent -a ~/.ssh-agent` and this *did* work when I tested an interactive connection with `SSH_AUTH_SOCK=~/.ssh-agent ssh -vvv ...`.

---

After staring at this for a while, on a hunch, I started getting suspicious of the tilde not being expanded when run as a windows service. So I tried setting the path with `/home/.../.ssh-agent`:

```
debug1: Offering public key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator agent
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: /home/.../.ssh/id_ed25519_sk ED25519-SK SHA256:... authenticator agent
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: using publickey with ED25519-SK SHA256:...
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com SHA256:...
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
Authenticated to ... using "publickey".
```

This was a long ride. Hopefully it helps someone else as well.